# Random "Cannot open user default database. Login failed." errors in winforms project

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-2008

I have a windows forms project working with service based database (.mdf file) on SQL server 2008 r2 express.
Recently random errors appeared when running the projects in different parts on the code with no pattern, sometimes it falls sometimes not so it hard to determine which part of the code causes this problem. The error message is:

> Cannot open user default database. Login failed. Login fail for user my_pc_name.

I have looked for solutions and found:
[Error in login to SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010062/error-in-login-to-sql-server)
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/11/04/sql-server-fix-error-4064-cannot-open-user-default-database-login-failed-login-failed-for-user/
both of them uses ssms to solve this but I when I tried to install it on the "select feature to install" it showed no features and I couldn't complete the installation.
The problem first appeared after I have added the following code to my main form to add drag feature, so maybe its related to it:

```
    public partial class Main: Form
{
    public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
    public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd,
                     int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();
            private void titleBar_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState != FormWindowState.Maximized&&e.Button==MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            ReleaseCapture();
            SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

I really can't figure out how to solve this and will appreciate any help.
Thanks.
**EDIT**
after debugging is saw that the problem comes from those lines

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
conn.Open();
```

as the connection string (created by method not written by me) is:

```
"DataSource=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\user\\Google Drive\\....\\App_Data\\CDDB.mdf(my db name);Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```

maybe the problem is here?

Comment: You can debug it and see from where the problem is coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved along with other problems. I think that the problem was that my solution folder was located in Google Drive folder and somehow the sync was making troubles. I'm not 100% sure that this is it but moving the folder to a regular folder solved it.